# VBA Suddenly calculating slower

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file that takes a formula, places it in a cell and autofills down then calculates. The sheet however takes a long time to calculate (crashes excel) whereas it used to take around a minute. Even manually doing the formulas takes ages to calculate for some reason.

About my sheet:
"Product List" is a list of 260,000 rows and there are three columns that need filled with formulas. This list expands downwards each week (i copy and paste a data list in)

The data tab (to get values from), has anywhere between 200,000 and 500,000 rows

The formula being filled is a sumifs into the data tab with only one criteria.

Code below (I did not write this so if the methods feel out of date then please let me know)

```
Sub PerfTest()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Call MainFormulas

ThisWorkbook.Save

MsgBox "Update Complete"
        
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub

Sub MainFormulas()

With Sheets("Product List")
    .Range("R2").Value = .Range("U1").Formula
    .Range("S2").Value = .Range("V1").Formula
    .Range("T2").Value = .Range("W1").Formula
End With

Call FillingFormulas("Product List", "R2", "R2", "A", 17)
Call FillingFormulas("Product List", "S2", "S2", "A", 18)
Call FillingFormulas("Product List", "T2", "T2", "A", 19)

End Sub

Sub FillingFormulas(Sheetname As String, FirstCellTopLineRange As String, TopLineRange As String, FullColumn As String, OffsetNo As Integer)

'Example1 is Call FillingFormulas("Delivery's By Line", "P7", "P7:Q7", "a", 16)
'Example1 is Call FillingFormulas("Delivery's By Line", "s7", "s7", "a", 18)

With Sheets(Sheetname)
    .Range(TopLineRange).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Range(FirstCellTopLineRange), _
    .Range(FullColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, OffsetNo)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    
    .Range(.Range(FirstCellTopLineRange), _
    .Range(FullColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, OffsetNo)).Calculate
    
    .Range(.Range(FirstCellTopLineRange), .Range(FullColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, OffsetNo)).Value = _
    .Range(.Range(FirstCellTopLineRange), .Range(FullColumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, OffsetNo)).Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this work on all the historical data as well as the fresh? Why not only work on the fresh and reduce the work?

Comment: How many criteria are there in your SUMIFS formulas? 260k rows * 3 columns is quite a lot of work to do

Comment: @SolarMike the formula is only related to the product list . We refresh the data from SQL and has to be done daily.

Comment: @Rory just the one criteria. I agree its a lot however it did used to work quickly.

Comment: If it takes ages manually too, it's probably nothing to do with the code. Perhaps you have a lot of volatile formulas?

Comment: It should only calculate once and then value after and from my understanding thats not volatile? I might just need to find another solution to be honest, or just do manually and be patient for 10 minutes